# What's the use of the method "of()"?

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns

I have seen this pattern in some places now...

1. What's the advantage?
2. what's the name if it's a Design Pattern?

```js
  /**
   * @description - Return the instance.
   * @returns - The instance.
   */
  public static of(): DecoratorBuilder {
    return new DecoratorBuilder();
  }
```

Comment: In which places? I have only seen `of` methods in other places, where they look quite different and fulfill a different purpose.

Comment: The doc comment is definitely wrong. It doesn't return *the* instance, it returns a new instance. (Unless there's some singleton shenanigans in the constructor?)

Comment: *"advantage"* compared to what?

Comment: Never seen `of` in this context and it actually seems misused here.

Comment: This looks like the Javascript equivalent of a [Static Factory Method](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-factory/info).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @jaco0646, this using the [Static Factory Method pattern](https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q&f=false), popularized by Joshua Bloch in Java. Note: This is different from the GoF design patterns Factory Method.